# Access Json element in Flow Variable - Mule 3.7

Tags: mule, mule-el, dataweave

Can we access a json element inside flow variables in Mule?

Eg: My flowVar value is `{
    "Input1": {
        "Value1": "UNITED STATES"
    }
}`

How can I access the element 'Value1' using MEL in mule?

Thanks, 
ROA

Comment: Is your flowVar the string representation of the above example or is it a HashMap or Stream or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right answer is

```
#[flowVars.theVariable.Input1.Value1]
```

but get here you need a lot what to do. You have to create variable appropriately to match your description. Also name of the variable is missed but you need it anyway. Here is code

```
    <flow name="AccessFlowVariable">
        <poll doc:name="Poll">
            <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="10000000"/>
            <logger message="Flow started" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </poll>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-variable variableName="theVariable"><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{ "Input1": { "Value1": "UNITED STATES" } }]]></dw:set-variable>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <logger message="#[flowVars.theVariable.Input1.Value1]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
```

and here is result
[image]

Comment: Your output on DW is Java, so the resulting type is (and is shown in your image above) is java.util.LinkedHashMap. So the dot notation works, I think he is asking that the flowVar is a string and not a hashmap.

Answer (score 1):

try the below expression,

```
#[json:/Input1/Value1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dw function or json path expression to achieve this.
examples:

## [dw('payload.Request.name')]

## [json:Request/name]

Answer (score -1):

"Can we access a json element inside flow variables in Mule?": Yes we can access json element inside flow variable.

"How can I access the element 'Value1' using MEL in mule?"
Let says if you have stored this json in flow variable (xyz) then you can access it using the bellow syntax:
flowVars.xyz.Input1.Value1